# Having issues logging in and crashing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, filesystem, freeze, crash

I'm running into a problem where my Ubuntu freezes at login or soon after logging in. I'm running it off of Oracle VM VirtualBox.
I get the following message before the login screen:

```
/dev/sda3: recovering journal  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: Clearing orphaned inode...  
/dev/sda3: clean, 642371/6569984 files, 10117686/26266624 blocks  
[ 107.124839] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 27s! [systemd"1]  
[ 206.125021] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 27s! [systemd"1]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!